# Can I use kettlebell like this also?

Tags: kettlebell

I already saw youtube videos on **kettlebell** but none does
like Tyler (Character) does in Never Back Down (2008) movie:

[image]

Can I use **kettlebell** like this also?

Answer (score 8):

Sure you can, but why would you want to? There is no benefit to slapping the kettlebell in mid-air.

If you're new to kettlebells, stick with the tried and true routines.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you need to know why you are doing it and that reason needs to work toward one of your goals.

Swinging like that and letting go will force you to produce enough power to get it high enough and be able to let go.

He is using one arm to swing and then he taps it several times. Great for hand-eye coordination and reaction time.